# How to format a LinkColumn as DateTimeColumn

Tags: django, django-tables2

I have a model with:

```
start_time = models.DateTimeField()
end_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

I've used django-tables2 and they both format in a friendly short date time format.

Now I change start_time in the table class to be a link using:

```
start_time = tables.LinkColumn('desturl', args[A('pk')])
```

And it's now formatted as the longer unfriendly date with timezone data.

Is there anyway of having both LinkColumn and DateTimeColumn used for the formatting? I can't spot anything in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to format the data as a URL, keep the column as a date field and use a [render_foo method](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#table-render-foo-methods) to render the date as a URL, e.g:

```
render_start_time(self,value):
    mark_safe('<a href="some_url">%s</a>' % value)
```

Hope this helps,

David

Answer (score 0):

As this is something you will likely want to reuse across tables and fields, a custom column is a good idea. For example, subclass DateTimeColumn and add the link with a call to BaselinkColumn.render_link:

```py
from django_tables2.columns.linkcolumn import BaseLinkColumn

class LinkedDateTimeColumn(tables.DateTimeColumn):
    def __init__(self, viewname, *args, **kwargs):
        self.viewname = viewname
        super(LinkedDateTimeColumn, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def render(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ts = super(LinkedDateTimeColumn, self).render(*args, **kwargs)
        view = reverse(self.viewname, args=[kwargs["record"].slug])
        return BaseLinkColumn().render_link(view, ts)

# in your tables
timestamp = LinkedDateTimeColumn('your_view_name', "d.m.Y H:i")
```

I've hardcoded the field for looking up the url to "slug" because all my models use it, but you can easily change it to "pk" or add it as an argument. Likewise, all optional arguments you can pass to [LinkColumn](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#django_tables2.columns.LinkColumn) are missing here - add back in what you need.